# Href link can't be clicked

Tags: php, html, css

I found a problem on my website, I can't click the href link.

On my offline test it works but when i upload to hosting, the link will not work. I included html and css coding on my website.

This is my css :

```
.footer-social-icon > a > i {
background:  #2e93fa;
font-size: 14px;
color: #ffffff;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
font-weight: 500;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
margin-right: 10px;}
```

This is my Html :

```
<div class="footer-social-icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/myavinofficial/"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/myavinofficial?igshid=mt79av9pihaq"> <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNtsL7TC0JfTiIjngA8dY9g"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=6289631925737&text=Halo%2C%20MyAVin!%20Ada%20yang%20ingin%20saya%20tanyakan%20nih."><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: You don't have anything in between your `a` tags, except an empty list item.  There's nothing there to click

Comment: I insert tag <i> with the font awesome to click

Comment: The code you have shown alone is not enough to reproduce your problem. Please provide a proper [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. Perhaps you forgot to add the font-awesome library. If you don't have the link, you are not able to display any information.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Try adding this to the head of the html file

Comment: Hi Kaya, can you tell me what version of font-awesome you are using?

Comment: We use font awesome 4.1.0 version.

Comment: when we try it offline we can click this but when I upload to hosting I can't click this

Comment: Interesting, I faced this issue once. I used the non-minified version => https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css . Sometimes the minifed files mess with the library

Comment: I have try with your link it can if we search our web on google but if we write manually on browser it not work. why sir? you can check on myavin.com